# How do I add a script to <head> on a specific page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, header

I want to add a script to the header section of a specific page on my WordPress site.

I figured it would just be a simple copy/paste, but I can't figure out where to put the code. I don't need the script to show up site-wide, just on a specific page.

Any ideas on where to start?

p.s. I'm using the Headway Theme for WordPress if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in wordpress functions to determine which page you're on pretty well.

- is_category() - Use this if you want to detect if a user is viewing a category page. Or if you want to detect a specific category you can use something like is_category('SEO Tips') for a category called 'SEO Tips'.
- is_single() - If user is viewing a post page. For a specific post use is_single(17) for a post with an id of 17. Or you can use is_single('Wordpress Tips') of a post with the title 'Wordpress Tips'.
- is_home() - as well.

You would do something like

```
if (is_category('that page you need')) { script }
```

Here is a list of wordpress conditional tags from the wordpress codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags